# EAS Push Client for C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any library I can use to get push emails from an EAS server? I'm using C# and ASP.NET.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's impossible to push data from server directly to your browser client.

But you can to check server for new messages every, let's say, 3 seconds and refresh your client interface.

Here is a good link [Comet implementations](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetComet.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to do anything with the client, the basic idea is I want to connect to an EAS server from my ASP.NET backend, and then subscribe for push notifications from that EAS server to my backend

Answer (score 0):

I ended up - er, I am now - writing my own quick & dirty EAS client for .NET. If anyone's interested I'll post the code up one Codeplex (after I figure out all the legalities of their licensing deals and such, of course).